# Wrong hostname that stop the application to produce output

Tags: deployment, openshift, kubernetes-ingress, podman

I have a pod that runs in a project, it's running, but the application does not produce output.

I noticed that the hostname is wrong, so I delete the route, the route was re-created by openshift with a different route-name but still having the wrong hostname.
How could I solve the problem? Should I change the ingress configuration? And if so, how could I do this, is there a special object that needs to be modified with the correct hostname to allow traffic from outside?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if „hostname“ in your case refers to the URL you are using in the Route or if it is refering to the Pod hostname.

For the Route, typically you can set any arbitrary value in the „.spec.host“ field. Then, when a HTTP request with this particular „Host“ HTTP header arrives at the OpenShift Router, it will be forwarded to your application. So you can edit the hostname in your Route to whatever you want.

As for the Pod hostname, this is set dynamically by OpenShift, so every Pod will have a different hostname set. You can look into StatefulSets or the „.spec.hostname“ fields of the Pod if you would like to change it.